# Only save png image not Jpg in clog

Tags: php, ios7, xcode5

I have next code and i only can save in WS images png, the camera images and JPG images downloaded cannot save in web service.
This code save right image PNG i try with UIImageJPEGRepresentation and UIImagePNGRepresentation but is the same result.
I have iOS7

```
NSData *originalPhoto = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imagenView.image,0.5f);
//NSData *originalPhoto =UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imagenView.image);
NSString *string = [originalPhoto base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];  // iOS 7+
NSString *encodedString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(                                                                                                       
NULL,                                                                                             
(CFStringRef)string,                                                                                  
NULL,                                                                               
CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]\" "),                                                                      
kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
// NSString *base64PhotoString = [originalPhoto base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

Comment: Exist some library for can do this conversion and can capture png or jpg with any problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, there  wasn't code ios,i can solved create php.ini in directory and put this lines:

```
upload_max_filesize = 16M;
post_max_size = 1000M;
extension=pdo.so;
extension=pdo_mysql.so;
```